# Custom Routes in Cakephp 3.7 to achieve the SEO Urls

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.7

I was using custom route controller like above in cakephp2.x, but now I have upgraded the cakephp. I would like to know how to achieve the same in cakephp3.7

earlier I used

```
App::uses('CakeRoute', 'lib/Cake/Routing/Route');

class CategoryRoute extends CakeRoute
{
    public function parse($url)
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url);
        if (empty($params)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and in router.php I used

```
App::import('Lib', 'CategoryRoute');
Router::connect('/paf/:page',array('controller' => 'Products','action' => 'liste'),array('pass' => array('paf'),'page' => '[0-9]+','routeClass' => 'CategoryRoute'));
```

to get the url like domain.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory

Comment: That custom route class does... nothing? And the route that you are showing doesn't match the URL that you are showing!?  Have you read **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html**? The routing basics are pretty much still the same.

Comment: the above route  was used by the previous developer and it was working in 2,x. Yes I have gone through the link already, but that is not working fine

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help you with "_doens't work_", you have to be more precise as to what _exactly_ your problem is. And again, the route that you are showing doesn't match the URL, so it's unclear what you're asking for, and the route class there, it doesn't do anything, other than returning an invalid value on success, returning `true` can cause the router, and the app in general to malfunction, as its expected to return either `false`, or an array of routing parameters.

Comment: https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/cakephp-routing-for-seo-urls-in-version-3-7/6326

I am not able to copy the actual categoryroute page here, so pasted the URL.
Hope this will make you more clear

Comment: I have written match and parse in the route class, but they are not overriding